# how to get the array in servlet which passed from ajax call

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am passing an array from servlet through ajax call. But when I am trying to get the same in servlet side, I am getting null pointer exception. I tried using one of the examples given in SO. Since I'm a newbie, any help would be appreciated!

```js
$.ajax({
    url : 'insertserv1',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {tablearray:tablearray} ,
          contentType: 'application/json',
          mimeType: 'application/json',
    success : function(data) {
       alert('Hi');
      }   
      });
```

```js
// to get data from inspection table
  { var tablearray = [];
   $("#tab_logic tr.data").map(function (index, tr) {
            $(this).find('td').each(function(){
                var $data = $(this).html();
                 if($(this).find("select").length > 0) {
                        var $x = $(this).find("select").val();
                    }else{
                   var $x = $(this).find("input[type='text']").val();
                }
                 tablearray.push($x);
            });   
         });
  }
```

```js
String[] tablearray = request.getParameterValues("tablearray[]");
  
for (int i = 0; i < tablearray.length; i++) {
  System.out.println(InspTableArray[i]);
}
```

Comment: When you hit  servlet , just debug the code and see what type of data you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, this is what you would be looking for:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader br = request.getReader();
    String str = null;
    while ((str = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sb.append(str);
    }
    try
    {
        jObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString()); //This is your JSON data.
    }
    catch (JSONException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Could you please highlight what was my mistake or what i missed to do. And one more thing when i tried to execute above code, i am getting error as "org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at 1 [character 2 line 1]"

Comment: The error means you would need to wrap the `tablearray` with the `{` and `}` characters so it can be considered as valid JSON. Maybe something like this would work: `jObj = new JSONObject("{" + sb.toString() + "}");`

Comment: You'll need to show us what the `tablearray` data looks like then, since that is the source of the error.

Comment: its like one row with 7 columns "typerating","asper", "ok", "ok", "ok", "ok", "ok". when i tired to print str. i got this tablearray%5B%5D=TypeRating&tablearray%5B%5D=AsperPO&tablearray%5B%5D=ok&tablearray%5B%5D=ok&tablearray%5B%5D=ok&tablearray%5B%5D=ok&tablearray%5B%5D=ok